# How to send message in telebot.py with None text?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

API says that you can't send message with no text but i have to show keyboard to user due to:

```
bot.send_message(id, text, markup = keyboard)
```

So how can i change keyboard or send another with no text?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update `KeyboardButtons` without sending texts.

Workaround,

- Send a dummy message with desired buttons and delete the message
  immediately.(Tip: use `disable_notification=True`, so user won't be
  notified of this message). Buttons will be updated

**UPDATE**

Deleting the message actually deletes the button too. `editReplyMarkup` doesnot work on`ReplyKeyboardMarkup` (the normal keyboard buttons)

You can use `InlineKeyboardButtons`, which can be edited (this is what I am using)

Comment: After deleting message with Reply Keyboard my keyboard is deleting too.

Comment: Normal `Keyboardbuttons` cannot be edited. Use `InlineKeyboardButtons` instead